# Jest & Enzyme. Find amount of all elements inside wrapper

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, enzyme

In jest & enzyme. How to find amount of all elements (children, children's children etc.) inside wrapper. `wrapper.children().length` outputs only direct children of wrapper

Comment: Did you try with `.find(cssSelector)`?

Comment: I need to find all nodes. How to do it with .find() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st easiest way:

Use `.find()` on each element in your component, so if your component has divs, h1 and a custom component called

Then you would do:

```js
const divs = wrapper.find('div');
const h1s = wrapper.find('h1');
const headers = wrapper.find(Header);

expect(divs.length + h1s.length + headers.length).toBe(yourExpect);
```

2nd dynamic way:

Use DFS or BFS recursion to loop through the wrapper children and it's children as well. Each node has a property of children on it which is an array (If I remember correctly) and you can then loop through each these and the length to an variable called numberOfElementsInComponent.

Something like this:

```js
let numberOfElementsInComponent = 0;

const dfsThroughNode = (node) => {
  if (node.children) {
    node.children.forEach((childNode) => {
      dfsThroughNode(childNode);
    });
  }
  numberOfElementsInComponent += 1;
};

it('yourTest', () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<Component />);

  wrapper.children().forEach((childNode) => {
    dfsThroughNode(childNode);
    numberOfElementsInComponent += 1;
  });

  expect(numberOfElementsInComponent).toBe(yourExpect);
});
```

Something like this for example.